# Why can't I see a created map when selected in hotbar?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I can't look at any map in my hotbar in minecraft. When I select it, nothing happens. I can't hold it in front of me. I can look at it on an Item Holder though. Any Suggestions?

Comment: It's Pocket Edition

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: @Rohan Then tag it as such. The [tag:minecraft] tag says that it's only for the original version of Minecraft. I know it's not ideal, since Microsoft renamed it, but the tag description tells you to not use it for MCPE.

Comment: I'll get it on as soon as possible. What do mean by Tag it as such?

Comment: file:///Users/19jansenr/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Mail%20Downloads/D5A1EEEB-AAC9-4DFF-ADE2-375050B70854/IMG_1487.PNG                              --Here's the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem- I had the “hide hand” setting on and that caused even maps to not be displayed in my hand! Switched it off and the maps came back.